# VBA code to pick/copy data based on multiple conditions

Tags: arrays, vba, excel-formula

I've been struggling to write this for days macro and I have finally decided to ask for your help.

Here's what I have in sheets:

Test - Job IDs, Assignees and Tasks as headers

A1 - IDs

B1 - Assignees

C1 - Tasks

*Rest of the headers are some excel formulas i've tried which did not work out.

- There are different no. of Jobs in the given data and each job has 2 tasks only. The tasks (task1 and task2) of each job are done by either 2 assignees separately or done by the same assignee (for some jobs).

What I am trying to achieve:

- I want to filter data in such a way that the macro should pick only five task1's and task2's of each assignee.
- But ideally, when a task2 of a job is picked, task 1 of the same job should also be picked keeping in mind that the assignee that did that task did not have more than 5 task1;s (or) task2's picked.
- My idea is, the macro should be able to ideally keep a log or delete data no. of tasks of a particular assignee once they reach the threshold of 5.
- To put it in simple terms, the no. of Job IDs picked do not matter, but when any job ID is picked, both task 1 and 2 of that job should be picked and each assignee should equally have 5 task1 and task2's.
- The IDs that don't meet the criteria can be ignored. But Finally the result should be this: Each assignee should have 5 task1's and task2's each but both task1 and and task2 of any job ID SHOULD be picked

I've tried using these excel formulas:

-I've concatenated the Assignee and tasks and check for repetition of the same throughout that column using =COUNTIFS($D$2:D2,D2)

-Now i've checked if each Job ID satisfies the given condition - =IF(AND(E3<=5,E2<=5),"Yes","No")

-This only resulted in filtering data that satisfies the condition but not enough data due to formulas' inability to automate the process of multiple conditions.

-In all respective sheets, i've put the desired result and result achieved.

I've tried some VBA code to filter out just the task1's of an assignee.

```
Sub Pick()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    a = Worksheets("Test").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To a
        If Worksheets("Test").Cells(i, 3).Value = "Task1" Then
            Worksheets("Test").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("IDs").Activate

            b = Worksheets("IDs").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            Worksheets("IDs").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            Worksheets("IDs").Paste
        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

[Please find the link of the excel file here](https://gofile.io/?c=RSSZ6H) - macro free

This is as far as i can get.

Comment: Please do not include links to download your macro-enabled file. It is unlikely anyone is going to download it as that can be dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I assure it has only the basic code i mentioned above. I can remove the macros and add it again